# Brain replacement for a Wii?

Tags: nintendo-wii

My mom's Wii has gotten to where it won't read disks, and my Wii has a fan that's gotten really noisy.

I have a spare Wii that I could scrounge for parts, and a tri-wing screwdriver, and I've been a long time user of iFixit, so have instructions ... but before I just steal parts from the relatively unused spare, I had two concerns:

1. Would it make more sense to try to move the effective 'brain' of one of the broken Wiis into the new system, rather than just move a single part?  (with the assumption that I'll have a relatively unused machine to work from, rather than two old machines with a single new part each)
2. If so, what's the part that needs to move?  (ie, where is the memory for the saved games that you can't write out to SD cards, like Super Smash Brothers?, the settings network settings, etc?).  I'm thinking a straight [mother board replacement](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-Nintendo-Wii-Motherboard/3460/1), but didn't know if it was hidden elsewhere, or on something removable from the memory board?

Comment: This... is not the best site for this kind of question. It's a valid question, mind, but it's about hardware, and not, explicitly, about games. I don't expect you'll find much help here.

Comment: @Raven: any suggestions for a better place to ask?

Comment: @Raven I think it has to be answered here if anywhere on SE.

Answer (score 1):

iFixit is your friend.  If you need to replace the Wii Drive and the Fan, the links below should get you the parts and walk you through the process.  FYI, I've never fixed a console of my own, but I've known about iFixit for years-- it's a pretty cool site to check out, even if you're not repairing your own hardware.

DVD Drive:
[Parts ($79.95)](http://www.ifixit.com/Game-Console-Parts/Nintendo-Wii-DVD-Drive/IF207-001)
[DVD Installation Instructions](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Nintendo-Wii-DVD-Drive-Replacement/5164/1)

Cooling Fan:
[Parts ($12.95)](http://www.ifixit.com/Game-Console-Parts/Nintendo-Wii-Fan/IF207-004)
[Fan Installation Instructions](http://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Repair/Installing-Nintendo-Wii-Fan/3459/1)

Comment: Thanks ... I used their instructions (and wow, did they bury the DVD drive in the Wii), but I ended up swapping out the DVD from the new Wii into the broken one, rather than try a full ['brain swap'](http://www.ifixit.com/Answers/View/51209/Where+is+the+%27identity%27+of+the+Wii+stored).